# IOS - how to prevent button in background from being tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, first-responder

I have a see through `UIView` in front of a `UIButton`. There are some other `UIView`s on the transparent `UIView` that the user can interact with.

How do I prevent the user from being able to click the button in the background?

I have tried to assign first responder status to the transparent `UIView`, but that doesn't work and doesn't make any sense because how would the user interact with the other visible `UIView`s on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set  `[self.myButton setEnabled:NO];` when your transparent view is open. Enable the button when you want to allow click

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

swift version

```
button.isEnabled = false
```

for navigation bar button

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
```

Comment: @jeb added for navigation bar button as you asked

Comment: ha ha.. my pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Objective -C

self.buttonName.isEnabled = YES; //button is Enabled
self.buttonName.isEnabled  = NO; // button is Disabled